# Audio data uri not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, uri

I'm developing an app that plays audios which source are data URI, and some URIs are not played in Chrome (debugger shows audio error 4). But in Firefox it works, and the data URIs seem ok because even Chrome, when the URI is pasted into the address bar, the audio is played.

This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/nyxglow/sd8c4cur/) shows a similar, but not equal, behavior:

a) Firefox (41.0.2) have no problems with "data URI" (URL does not work in jsfiddle because I cannot attach the source audio file)

b) Chrome (46.0.2490.71 (64-bit)) plays only once

Thank you

Code:

```
<script>

    function playURI() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('audioURI');
        elem.src = '-;
        if (elem.error !== null) {
            console.log('Error ' + elem.error.code);
        } else {
            elem.play();
        }
    }

    function playURL() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('audioURL');
        elem.src = "voluntary-187.mp3"
        if (elem.error !== null) {
            console.log('Error ' + elem.error.code);
        } else {
            elem.play();
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="playURI()">Data URI</button>      
        <audio id="audioURI"></audio>

        <button onclick="playURL()">URL</button>      
        <audio id="audioURL"></audio>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oddly enough, the problem does not happen if the jsfiddle is opened in a new tab, but it does when no new tab is used.

Comment: Maybe it's this same issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543808